# Can I determine if an application is being run normally vs via a unittest in Python?

Tags: python, logging, python-unittest

I've inherited an application that desperately needs some unit testing. The problem I have is that the application has a log set up that logs to both the console and a file like so:

```
def setup_logging(file_name, file_level=logging.INFO, console_level=logging.INFO):
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # Create Console handler
    console_log = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_log.setLevel(console_level)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)-s - %(name)-s - %(message)s')
    console_log.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(console_log)

    # Log file
    file_log = RotatingFileHandler('logs/%s.log' % (file_name), 'a', MAX_LOG_SIZE, MAX_LOGS_SAVE, encoding='UTF-8')
    file_log.setLevel(file_level)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)-s - %(name)-s - %(message)s')
    file_log.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(file_log)

    return logger
```

The logging in the application is fairly extensive too. When I run a unit test and it triggers a log message, my unit test output is messed up:

```
>python tests.py
2014-10-23 09:47:28,857 - INFO - funct_1 -  args =>
.2014-10-23 09:47:28,871 - INFO - funct_1 -  args => name=unicode<Andy>
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.040s

OK
```

Is there a way to determine if an application is being run via `unittest` so that I can remove the console log events?

This is a flask application, but I don't think that will matter for the end result here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess.

myapp/main.py

```
testing = __name__ != "__main__"
```

myapp/logging.py

```
from myapp.main import testing

if testing:
    ...
```

Or you could try:

myapp/testing.py

```
import myapp.main
import __main__

testing = vars(myapp.main) is not vars(__main__)

del myapp
del __main__

# import myapp.testing rather than myapp.main
```

Though what you really want is a way to tell your logging module to produce different loggers depending on how its been setup. One way of doing that is to initially have the logging module produce no or little logging, and then have the first thing main do is to setup up the logging module with the appropriate level of logging, before any loggers have been produced.

eg.

myapp/main.py

```
# start of file
import myapp.logging
myapp.logging.setlevel(myapp.logging.DEBUG)

# rest of imports

# rest of main
```

Alternatively you could have logging on at a high level by default and turn it off for testing. One way of doing this is creating a parent package inside your test source directory. Put all your test modules inside the parent package and then create an `__init__` module. This init module will be run before any of your test modules are even loaded. Thus, it can turn off logging before any of your test modules even exist in memory.

eg.

testsrc/parentpackage/__init__.py

```
import myapp.logging
myapp.logging.setlevel(myapp.logging.ERROR)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a Flask application you should change which configuration is being loaded at application startup. The link to the Flask documentation is [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/). There are generally a few ways to handle this. Once you've got that all set up you can check app.config['TESTING'] or do any one of a million things.

Answer (score 0):

I would set the logging to 'logging.ERROR' for both file and console logging when you run the unittests.